# "isnan" doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, input, numeric

Simply trying to catch non numeric input
Read MANY items . Tried decimalDigitCharacterSet (found it hard to believe that something that starts with the word "decimal" doesn't contain a decimal). Tried mutable character set to add the decimal.  Been working to include "10.5" with "96" and still exclude "abc".

the following code produces "IS a number" no matter what I put in textbox1

```
double whatTheHey;

whatTheHey = _textBox1.text.doubleValue;

if isnan(whatTheHey) {
    _textBox2.text = @"NOT a number > ";
}

if (!isnan(whatTheHey)) {
    _textBox2.text = @"IS a number > ";
}
```

10.5 , 99 , qwerty   all yield "IS a number"

This seems like a heck of a lot of work just to catch non numeric input.

Does anybody have any blatantky simple examples of working code to catch non numeric but accept numbers with decimal in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check wether a string is numeric or not use the following piece of code.

```
    NSString *newString = @"11111";
    NSNumberFormatter *nf = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    BOOL isDecimal = [nf numberFromString:newString] != nil;
```

Comment: Thanks to all! - this is one I was able to get to work - I imagine the other solutions work as well - I might not have applied them correctly - Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` does *not* literally mean "anything that is not a number". It is the name of a specific value — namely one floats can have after certain indeterminate operations such as dividing zero by zero or taking the square root of a negative number. See [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) for more history.

To actually parse the numeric value of a string, you probably want to look into [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *a = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"10.5"];
NSNumber *b = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"96"];
NSNumber *c = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"abc"];
NSLog(@"a: %@, b: %@, c: %@", a, b, c);
```

Yields:
`a: 10.5, b: 96, c: (null)`

A simpler (if less flexible) solution that meets your specific criteria might be:

```
BOOL isNumber(NSString *aString){
  return [aString integerValue] || [aString floatValue];
}
```

But if you're writing for iOS (or OS X), you really ought to get comfortable with the `NSFormatter`s. They'll make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for all the info and advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think it should do what you need:

```
- (BOOL)isStringNumeric:(NSString *)input {
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:input];
    return (number != nil);
}
```